# Why was my question closed?

Tags: discussion, off-topic, closed-questions, flagging

I asked:  ["Where can I find historical world stock returns? [closed]"](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/118283/where-can-i-find-historical-world-stock-returns) and it was flagged as off topic.

How is this off topic? I'm just asking if anyone knows where I can find a chart showing total world stock returns (like an international Dow Jones Industrial Average). So that I can have a sense of how international index funds have performed relative to US based index funds historically, allowing me to make inferences about future performance and choose what to invest in.

Answer (score 2):

> Questions seeking product, service recommendations or other off-site
>   resources are off-topic because they tend to become obsolete quickly.
>   Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're
>   trying to solve.

The above quote comes form the header above your original question.

The chart you seek might be available now, but it might not be available in the future. That is the reason why these types of questions are closed. There is no mechanism to keep the answers to these types of questions from going stale.

Comment: That doesn't really make any sense though. If I'd asked if someone could point me towards a chart showing 100 years of the Dow Jones Industrial Average that could be easily done and I doubt anyone would have any objections, and if the person was concerned about the website eventually removing the information they could even paste the image in place. Why should it be different to see 100 years of international equities? I don't care what index is used, I'm just trying to understand how long-term growth of international equities compares to US based ones.